# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1-1/x)^x$ using l'Hospital's rule.

Tags: calculus, limits

The problem is $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1-1/x)^x$$

I took the natural log and got:

$x\ln (1-(1/x))  $

What do i do now? My brain is clogged it seems I forgot how to simplify the expression inside $\ln$, help?

Comment: As $x \to 0^+$, $(1-\frac1x) \to -\infty$ and $\ln (1-\frac1x)$ is no more defined...

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos The only way the limit equals $1$ is if your only coming from the negative side. If you're coming from the positive side, then the limit is clearly undefined because you're taking negative numbers to rational powers, which gets into complex numbers.

Comment: Better to not link to a problem where the link will likely disappear after time. Rather, simply write the problem here.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Please, look the solution down below. Also : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+(1-1%2Fx)%5Ex+as+x-%3E+0

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos Oh, so the imaginary part converges to $0$. Sorry about that. I did not know L'Hopital's rule works for complex numbers like this.

Comment: No problem, just generally think simpler. The way of expressing functions and limits to the exponent form is pretty common and really really useful in calculus, so keep that in mind ! :)

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} (1 - 1/x)^x & =  \lim_{x \to 0} \exp(x\ln(1 - 1/x)\\
 &  \\
 & = \exp \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(1 - 1/x)}{1/x} \right) \\ 
 &  \\
 & = \text{l'Hospitals rule} \\
 &  \\
 & = \exp \left(\lim_{x \to 0} -\frac{x}{x-1}\right) \\ 
 &  \\
 & =1
\end{align}

Comment: Good call, that's the correct answer !

Comment: How are you defining the logarithm with negative argument?

Comment: See the other answer and [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%281-1%2Fx%29^x+as+x-%3E+0)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what [@JKnecht](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/298619/jknecht) did is actually valid, despite my previous comments, but I would like to point something out that he did not.

From the positive side, under the real numbers, this is undefined. This is because as $x$ approaches $0^+$, $1-1/x$ goes to $-\infty$, meaning $\log(1-1/x)$ is complex. Therefore, this limit is a complex limit which happens to converge to $0$ and can be solved using L'Hopital's rule, but without the complex numbers, this limit is undefined.

Comment: This problem approaches x from the positive side.

Comment: @kounliu I'm sorry for the confusion, I've edited my answer completely.

Answer (score -1):

Write:
$$ lny = \frac{ln [1-(1/x)]}{\frac{1}{x}} $$

Now, if you are looking for x goes to infinity, you have type $0/0$, and you have  and if x goes to zero you have type $\infty/\infty $. In both cases, L'Hopital applies: take derivatives and evaluate.

Comment: I know that $1/x$ goes to infinity but 1 minus infinity is what? Negative infinity?

Comment: $1/x$ cannot go to $+\infty$ because $\ln$ would not be defined then. So, I assume that $1/x$ goes to $-\infty$. Then  $1-1/x$ goes to $+\infty $, which means that its log goes to infinity.